# mod rewrite exclude all but php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to edit htacces in such a way that only the following url is rewritten and the rest isn't?

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?x=foobar
 to
http://www.example.com/foobar/
```

I want the pages not having x=... as a variable to behave normally

I got the following but that doesn't work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?x=$1
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `RewriteCond` must be put before the `RewriteRule` to which it belongs.

But I think that you need another approach for your case, something like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?x=$1
```

- The first rule Passes Through (PT) every PHP page, so the second rule is only applied to all non-PHP requests.
- That second rule only applies to a "simple path", no matter if this path has a dot in it or not (e.g. `hello.gif/` will match, too).

If this does not work for you, then you might consider one of these points to start further research:

- the pattern `([^\.]*)` matches everything that does not have a dot in it
- see [RewriteCond to skip rule if file or directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030731/rewritecond-to-skip-rule-if-file-or-directory-exists) for `RewriteCond`s where the following `RewriteRule` is only used if the request does not point to an existing file or directory

Hope this helps.