# How to create Generic RewriteRule for slash separated url parameters in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to get my data from url witch are slash separated like this:

> www.example.com/page.php/12

witch must interpreted to:

> www.example.com/page.php?id=12

I wont to specify page name like "page.php" in my .htaccess and it must be generic like "*.php". 
i use this lines but this change my baseUrl and my css are not accessible:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  $1.php?id=$2
```

Comment: You don't need a rewrite rule for this as you can use `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` to get the same `/12` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

See [RewriteCond to skip rule if file or directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030907/1992669): you should add conditions to not redirect requests to existing files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  $1.php?id=$2
```