# RewriteCond if file exists in directory of request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write htaccess rules that would rewrite my requests in a folder if a specific file exists in that directory. I have found a couple of similar problems ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030731/rewritecond-to-skip-rule-if-file-or-directory-exists)), but all refer to a file in a specific directory, whereas in my case, the directory is the one of the request.

**Example:**

```
Root
 |
 -- Folder1
 |  |
 |  -- mywebpage.php
 |
 -- Folder2
    |
    -- meta.json
    -- mywebpage.php
```

I want to rewrite every request in any folder which has meta.json.

```
Request1: /Folder1/mywebpage.php --> Not rewritten
Request2: /Folder2/mywebpage.php --> Rewritten
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dunno if that works, but have you tried something like `RewriteCond 'meta.json' -f`? (Or maybe without the single quotes) I'd assume that would check relative to the current directory; although I can not find exact definition of the behavior in the docs.